# Happy Mother's Day, mom! Usage of はは and おかあさん

Tags: word-choice

In a social media post, i want to say happy Mother's day to my mom (but is visible to everyone).

I came up with 幸｛さち｝せな母｛はは｝の日｛ひ｝、お母｛かあ｝さん .

Would this be considered normal for a native speaker?  Is the usage of haha and kaa correct if i were to speak or to her?

Comment: 幸 is さち, but 幸せ is しあわせ.

Answer (score 6):

As a Mother's Day message to your mother, 「お[母]{かあ}さん いつもありがとう」 is more common and would be considered normal by most native speakers.

Saying 「[母]{はは}の[日]{ひ}おめでとう」 to your own mother sounds a bit strange.  「～～おめでとう」 is usually used for celebrating New Year's Day or someone's birthday etc., or congratulating someone's entering school, graduation, promotion etc.

Comment: 「おめでとう」は、慶事・祝事・新年を祝う言葉です。父の日・母の日・敬老の日・バレンタインデーなどはそれにあたりませんので、「おめでとう」はおかしいです。参考: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/655243.html ・ https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13177767633 ・ https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13545773